# Intercepting the mouse coordinates and modifying it

Tags: macos, mouse

I would like to create an app that intercepts the mouse coordinates and modify them.

I want to build an app that runs in the background and intercepts the mouse movement, filtering it, for all apps running on macOS.

Suppose the mouse is scrolling freely but if the user presses a global shortcut, like CMD ALT X, the vertical scrolling is filtered and just the horizontal scrolling passes to macOS.

First question: what should I use to do that? Just point me in the right direction if the topic is too extensive.

Second question: is that possible to do for a sandbox app?

Comment: You need to install a `CGEventTap`; you can read the event stream and modify events

Comment: thanks. Can this be used with sandboxed apps?

Comment: It [seems possible](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707680) if you grant your application the proper privileges